# Release build package issue

Tags: c#, package, nuget, nuget-package

There's a function that is called from a NuGet package when the program starts up, and if I start the program in debug or release build in VS 2017 it works just fine, no issues - this has been tried on multiple machines.

If we queue it for a release build on our build server and launch the program it builds on one of the PCs where it worked (or any other PC) we get the following error:
[image]

It's possible that the NuGet on the build server is pulling the wrong version of the package that's causing the error, but I've cleared the NuGet cache and I still get the same issue (Although there is an extra NuGet install on the PC which I can't clear or update).

This build server has been creating release builds for years, it has only started to happen recently, and with this specific branch of code.

Any thoughts on what could/might cause a package issue on a release build on a build server would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with some DLL's in the source which were out of date and only got copied over in the build server itself. Nothing to do with NuGet or C#.

The fault was with the build scripts we created and how the build server builds release builds differently.